# How can I navigate from the MenuItem to a fragment (Android)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I have a `MainActivity` and 3 different Fragments. The toolbar I created in `MainActivity` appears in all 3 Fragments I have. And I can switch between these Fragments using the button.

As an example;

```
binding.buttonSelectFile.setOnClickListener(v -> NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_ThirdFragment));
```

I want to create a similar behavior for the Toolbar item. For example, every time the user presses a "help" item defined as below, I want the application to navigate to the `HelpFragment`.

```
<menu 
    <!-- other items -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_help"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I tried to do something like this in the onCreate() method of the MainActivity class, purely as a guess.

```
binding.toolbar.getMenu().getItem(R.id.action_help).setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.HelpFragment);
            return true;
        });
```

However, this method is of course not correct.

Is such use possible? Or should I follow another way to show the help screen to the user?

Comment: How do you build items in the toolbar.. is that the `supportActionBar`, or a custom toolbar in the layout?

Comment: I am calling the setSupportActionBar() method for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am calling the setSupportActionBar() method for it

So, the `action_help` menu item is a part of the default optionsMenu. Then you need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to inflate the menu, and `onOptionsItemSelected` to handle the click on the `R.id.action_help` menu item.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu); // replace "my_menu" with the name of your menu xml file
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_help) {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment); // replace "nav_host_fragment" with the id of your navHostFragment in activity layout
        navController.navigate(R.id.HelpFragment);
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've seen the "nav_host_fragment" part before but didn't understand what they meant. Your answer was very clear.